# What is the best way to sync FTP data with amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

I am planning to write a java program that synchronizes non existing FTP data with Amazon S3 at specific time interval. Here i am planning to skip the files/folders that are already copied/uploaded to S3. Is this a best possible way with good performance to achieve this functionality? or shall i find some other way to achieve this? If java program is good enough to design it, would like to know the best possible strategies i shall apply to achieve the best performance out of it.

Comment: Just install the AWS CLI tool and run an `aws s3 sync` command via cron.

Answer (score 0):

**S3fs** is the best option if you are using FTP.

You can install fuse on your machine and mount a point to access S3 directly. Make the FTP home directory as your mount point so that whenever any data is uploaded to home it goes directly into s3.

**NOTE:** (When something is deleted from s3 or home directory it reflects in s3 bucket)